# Android Studio Tools -> Firebase doesn't work, IDE Error occuring

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-assistant

When I try to open the Firebase assistent in Tools > Firebase an IDE Error occurs.
I've already tried to reinstall the Google Repository needed for this tool, reactivating the firebase plugins, and also reinstalled Android Studio (though without deleting all user settings).

```
Android Studio 3.1.3
Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

IDE Error:
Exeption in plugin **Firebase Services**. Moments ago. Occured 2 times since last clear. Undread. *Disable Plugin.*

```
null
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$1.next(Iterators.java:81)
    at com.google.services.firebase.DependencyStateManager.getDependencyState(DependencyStateManager.java:60)
    at com.google.services.firebase.DependencyStateManager.init(DependencyStateManager.java:109)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.StatefulButton.<init>(StatefulButton.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.TutorialStep.<init>(TutorialStep.java:106)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.TutorialCard.redraw(TutorialCard.java:153)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.TutorialCard.<init>(TutorialCard.java:90)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.view.FeaturesPanel.<init>(FeaturesPanel.java:84)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.AssistSidePanel.<init>(AssistSidePanel.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.AssistToolWindowFactory.createToolWindowContent(AssistToolWindowFactory.java:37)
    at com.android.tools.idea.assistant.OpenAssistSidePanelAction.lambda$openWindow$0(OpenAssistSidePanelAction.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: @PeterHaddad oops, confused the date with the year... my fault (retracted that vote). however, when the `getDependencyState()` within the `AssistSidePanel` does not return elements, the iterator cannot iterate.

Comment: nevertheless, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602725/firebase-assistant-fails-to-launch-flutter

Answer (score 1):

A quick search brought up the following procedure to fix the issue:

- go to Settings > Plugins.
- remove all Firebase plugins.
- restart Android Studio.
- back to Settings > Plugins.
- enable the Firebase plugins again.
- restart Android Studio.

Comment: I probably didn't communicate it good, what i meant with "reactivating the firebase plugins" was exactly that routine, but it doesn't work for me.
Like I said I also already reinstalled Android Studio and reinstalled the Google Repository, but nothing's working.

Comment: @JSANL. you might not have deleted the IDE's cache within the user profile, which may subsequently lead to issues which appear to be persistent (also the permissions there may interfere with the "invalidate caches" function).

Comment: Ah okay, do you have an idea how I could delete the IDE's cache within the user profile / solve this problem?

Comment: got to the home directory and just delete it?

Comment: please elaborate. I've deinstalled Android Studio even with the option of deleting all user settings (which didn't happen somehow, it still opend directly with the old theme and in my last used file).

Comment: @JSANL. it sounds as if you might have messed up your file-system permissions and should **delete the directory manually**, just as I've suggested. you've did something else instead - and now complain it does not work. and I'm amazed, because this question is two years old.

Comment: I didn't temper with file-permissions. After searching I saw that Android Studio seems to save the user config at C:\Users\[User]\.AndroidStudio3.1.It doesn't delete it (atleast on my system) even with selecting to delete all User settings when deinstalling. And no, I didn't temper with any file-system permissions.
So now i've deinstalled Android Studio several times completely, **with** user settings and did everything with the plugins like described and it's still not working. Do you have an idea what could cause it?

Comment: Also I just noticed that you meant that exact folder, but I didn't know that this folder was existing. So if you just tell me to "go there and delete it" I can't follow as I didn't know what folder

Comment: @JSANL. on Windows, run the `cmd` prompt, as Administrator, and then enter `rmdir /S C:\Users[User]\.AndroidStudio3.1`. or run the explorer as Administrator ...if you cannot delete that under a user account, it was installed under an admin account.

Comment: the problem is not that I can't delete it, but that it doesn't help with the plugin problem. I've deleted it manually when deinstalling already several times

Comment: @JSANL. why you don't just leave those plugins disabled? they're only good for adding Firebase to a project (which also can be accomplished by copy & paste). rather install the Fabric plugin.